# disable characters from being entered in textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building a form and i want to prevent certain characters from being typed in a textbox? 
I want to disable the " and ' characters in some of my textboxes

Comment: No, you don't.  You want to use parameters in your SQL queries.

Comment: i am using parameters in my queries, but i also want to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) along with a regex such as `[^"']` to allow all characters except `"` and `'`.

(please note, that regex is untested at the moment...)

ASP.NET Validators have both client and server APIs for validation.

Comment: How could i use the required field validator and regularexpressionvalidator together

Comment: @whatsupprogrammers: you can use multiple validators on the same control.

Answer (score 1):

Using an [AJAX ASP FilterTextBox Control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) would be the way I'd go.

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TARGETCONTROLIDHERE"         
    FilterType="Custom, Numbers, LowerCaseLetters, UpperCaseLetters, Symbols"
    InvalidChars="&" />
```

Comment: i would put the characters i want to allow in ValidChars="&" , would i have to type all the letters in there too

Comment: @whatsupprogrammers no, the FilterType specifies what main sets you want to use `(UpperCaseLetters, LowerCaseLetters, Numbers, Symbols)` those are the defaults. Then if you wanted to prevent the & symbol you would simply not define that symbol, or if you need all the other symbols, define symbols in the FilterType, and use the `InvalidChars` to remove the &. and it would prevent it from appearing in your box. With VB 2005, im not sure how thats works I use 2008 so you may need to look around for info on that.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to check the form values on the server-side to see if the input is valid (doesn't include quote characters in your case) and respond with an error if it is invalid.

On the client side, I've had good luck using jQuery Validation.

Remember that arbitrary form payloads can be constructed outside of a browser, so you always have to check data validity on the server, even if client-side validation is in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove those characters from the string before you perform your database operation.

Comment: `yourString` = `yourString.Replace("'","")`